# Including a local Javascript module dependency in Intellij Idea using Gradle

Tags: javascript, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

I have an Intellij Idea project that has two modules, one module is a Kotlin/JS module (module A), the other a Javascript/node.js module (module B). Module A can create a bundled Javascript file using a gradle task called browserProductionWebpack (or browserDevelopmentWebpack). What is the best way to set it up so that the Module B has the Module A bundled javascript file as a dependency? I'm not sure what the canonical way to do this would be.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main ways to do this.

### First - `binaries.library()`

You can use the `binaries.library()` flag in your gradle JS definition, and this library itself will be consumable by Webpack. To do this you would include a direct path to the file in the package.json

build.gradle.kts

```
kotlin {
  js(IR) {
    moduleName = "moduleA"
    binaries.library()
    
    compilations["main"].packageJson {
      customField("name", "myJsModule")
    }
  }
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "web",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": "true",
  "dependencies": {
    "myJsModule": "file:../../moduleA/build/production"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "gradle :myProjectName:moduleA: browserProductionWebpack"
  }
}
```

There are 2 keys within this file.

First the "myProjectName" definition is hard coded to the folder containing a `binaries.library()` output.

Second the script definition of `preinstall` will run the gradle task as part of running the `npm install`. This is a shortcut, but not necessary.

### Second - Gradle Plugin for NPM packaging

There are multiple plugins available to do this work via Gradle, and then package an NPM package that is usable from a standard JS project. This can be "hosted" locally, and we would do the same path based structure mentioned above, or you can push it to NPM and have NPM help with that registration.

For this method, one possible plugin is:
[npm-publish](https://github.com/mpetuska/npm-publish)

They have the NPM based instructions in their README, and this is another method to consume the output of your gradle build.